# Quicktime deprecated but it was deleted

Tags: macos, quicktime, mac-app-store, qtkit

I get the error when I try upload my app to the Mac App Store:

"Deprecated API Usage. Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use Quicktime APIs"

However I've removed QTKit and Quicktime frameworks and migrated to AVFoundation. The error still appear and I've checked all my project and QTKit and Quicktime framework were deleted. I don't know if I have to do something else.

I've sought QuickTime APIs in my application using by running the nm command-line tool against your application binary.

```
 nm -m "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp"  | egrep "QuickTime|QTKit"
```

and I didn't find anything. All was ok. I'm so frustrated :-(

Comment: Does your app package contain any frameworks, dylibs, or helper apps/tools?  If so, you'd need to check those binaries too.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I have a helper app but I've checked it too. How could I check the frameworks and dylibs?

Comment: A dylib is a binary, while for a framework, you would usually need to go into Versions/A to find the binary.  By the way I would use `otool -L` instead of `nm -m`.

Comment: The result is the same. otool doesn't detect quicktime in my project but I can't upload the binary :-(

Comment: Try this GUI version of `otool` which may be more convenient to use: https://code.google.com/p/macdependency/